# Sklearn Lightgbm 3.3.2 API

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I have a model object from a model and am trying to pass in the dataframe for scoring, it is kicking me an error:

```
ValueError: train and valid dataset categorical_feature do not match.
```

That is fine, but is there a way I can extract which columns from the training set are which dtypes from the model object so I can go correct the dataframe?